# Adding markers to Mapbox with additional features

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am developing a flutter application in which I am using Mapbox to add turn-by-turn navigation.  I have been looking at some tutorials to add markers to the map. However, I also want to give the user awareness of these specific points through voice output.
Is it possible to achieve this objective? Any resources or advice that you could provide, please?

Edit: How can I integrate the text to speech with the custom mapbox on my flutter app? For the Mapbox, we simply run the following code to enable voice instructions.

```
voiceInstructionsEnabled: true,
```

So how can I add the text conversion with it?

Truly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can do it separately.

You can show markers on map with Mapbox
and prepare a string with all marker labels and use [flutter_tts](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts) package to convert to speech as follows:

```
Future _speak() async {
await flutterTts.setVolume(volume);
await flutterTts.setSpeechRate(rate);
await flutterTts.setPitch(pitch);

if (_newVoiceText != null) {
  if (_newVoiceText!.isNotEmpty) {
    await flutterTts.speak(_newVoiceText!);
  }
}
```

}

This snippet is taken from the example given in documentation:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tts/example

Comment: Where should I actually add it so that it syncs with the map, please?

Comment: I am using code from https://github.com/Imperial-lord/mapbox-flutter/blob/main/turn_by_turn/completed_code/mapbox_turn_by_turn/lib/screens/turn_by_turn.dart

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to start nativation?
Its this line in given link : 'await directions.startNavigation(wayPoints: wayPoints, options: _options);', Also did you follow the documentation and did the android/ios related configurations?

Comment: Above code is for text to speech, but in your case(as the question became clearer after the edit), the exitsting flutter_mapbox_navigation plugin is enough for the job

Comment: do I need to remove the flutter_mapbox_navigation plugin and do it from scratch to be able to integrate the flutter_tts package?

Comment: You don't need flutter_tts_package, your existing code should be aliright, 
try the example from here: 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_mapbox_navigation/example

Comment: What about constantly reading the current location and then outputting audio when the user is at that particular position.